# Socket programming using Tkinter got stuck

Tags: sockets, tkinter

I'm implementing socket programming using Tkinter. I'm using a button to start the server. When I click on the button the server has started, but the GUI gets stuck. It isn't displaying anything. In the terminal I'm able see that the server has started and the client is connected,
but not in the GUI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software libraries involved but this sounds like a bug report for some GUI program more than an answerable question. Did you write any code/configuration to set this up? If so, could you share so someone might be able to help? Any screenshots to show exactly what is happening?

Comment: Are you using another thread for your socket server?  If not, then waiting for connection will block the tkinter mainloop.